# Can I use grape on soapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I really don't know If I can or not since I've been researching on the internet and I haven't seen anything about this topic.

If I try to use the following on soapui (groovy script)

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab(group='net.sf.json-lib',
    module='json-lib',
    version='2.3',
    classifier='jdk15'),
  @Grab('xom:xom:1.2.5')
])
import net.sf.json.JSONObject
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer
```

I'm getting an error on Soapui that says "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/settings/lvySettings" , So I really don't know If grape is not possible to be used on soapUI or I'm failing on some step.

Thank you guys.

Comment: It doesn't currently work out-of-the-box.  There's a feature request that you can upvote: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Feature-Requests/Adding-Groovy-Grape-dependency-management-out-of-the-box/idi-p/130390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but I have to add ant jar and ivy jar to soapui/bin/ext otherwise it's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer does not work for SoapUI 5.7.0, you must add the Ivy JAR to `%SOAPUI_HOME%..\lib`

Source: [R2 Blog](https://rupz.me/soapui-cookbook-bonus-recipes/r2-soapui-groovy-grape-dependencies/)