# Import libraries in groovy script - SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SOAP UI for a while now but got stuck with strange thing last night. I'm using a framework that has all sort of libraries and stuff imported in groovy scripts and is working just fine on windows but when my colleagues tried to use the same framework in mac, the groovy script doesn't just run.

Below is the error:

> ```
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup 
>     failed: Script2.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class
>     com.automation.support.HtmlReportSupport @ line 1, column 1. import
>     com.automation.support.HtmlReportSupport; ^
> ```

I know this error looks familiar but I can't really locate where exactly that com.automation.support....

Is located just to see if I'm missing any of the libraries.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by myself.

As per my framework, I need to place libraries in app > lib. To do that on MacOS Sierra, please follow these steps

- Open Finder and click on 'Applications' from the side bar
- In the applications folder, locate SoapUI icon, Right click on it and select "Show Package Contents"
- Now your navigation should be Contents > java> app > lib
- Place your libraries in lib folder
- Your framework or setup may require to place your external libraries in lib folder

Hope that works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the respective libraries missing.

Copy them under `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory and restart the tool.

Since you said, it is working on one machine, check above directory on the working machine and copy them over to mac machine.

That should resolve.

Comment: This might sound dumb but how can I export path for SOAPUI_HOME coz I'm not sure about the location

Comment: It is just the location where soapui software is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Grapes/Ivy dependency management, although this requires modifying the SoapUI installation to add the required JARs.

[Can I use grape on soapUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486025/can-i-use-grape-on-soapui)