# Grab does not download dependency in soap ui

Tags: groovy, soapui, ivy, groovy-grape

I am trying to download a dependency via `@Grab` in SOAP UI, running the below script

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.3')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
    
def csv = '''Name,Lastname
Mark,Andersson
Pete,Hansen'''
    
def data = parseCsv(csv)
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.Name $line.Lastname"
}
```

I am getting this error

[image]

Here are the JAR's I am using in SOAP UI `ext` folder

[image]

What is the problem and how do you fix this so that Grab downloads the dependencies.

```
Groovy Version: 4.0.6
```

Comment: You have to have the ivy and dependent jars in your SopaUI lib directory.

Comment: @ou_ryperd I have them

Comment: Which version of SoapUI are you using that ships with Groovy 4.0.6 ? Run this in SoapUI: `log.info GroovySystem.version`

Comment: SoapUI 5.6.0 uses Groovy 2.4.17. Here are the compatable ivy and ant libraries: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use grape on soapUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486025/can-i-use-grape-on-soapui)